# How do I change letters in this list in python?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a program that allows you to decode messages in python. Here's what I got so far...

```
def decode():
    print("Let's see what she wanted to tell you.")
    time.sleep(2)

    messageOne= raw_input('Please paste the message: ')
    print("Decoding message now...")

    message= list(messageOne)
```

and I was wondering how I would take the individual letters in the list and change them based on the code I want. Aka I need to know how to change a specific value in the list. Thanks!

Comment: string.replace()? https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Comment: How does the code work? string.replace will work if it's doing things like replacing all Es with 3s.

Comment: @raul.vila so now I've incorporated that but it sends back an error: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Comment: messageOne = messageOne.replace("xxx", "yyy") # if messageOne is "My xxx string" then it will replaced with "My yyy string"

Comment: "Based on the code I want" is very vague. Will you always replace one character with one other character, nothing more complicated?

Comment: @Elliot `replace` is a method of `string` not `list`, so the above recommendation is to call this before you convert to `list`. Do you want to change every instance of a value, just the first or some other. My recommendation is to formulate your question with some specified input and clearly state the output you expect. This clears things up a lot for anyone trying to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, based on what I see you can have different ways of replacing letters. For example let's use string s:

```
>>> s = 'Hello'
>>> s.replace('l','h')
Hehho
```

If you only want to replace one occurrence of a given letter use this:

```
>>> s = 'Hello'
>>> s.replace('l','h', 1) #will only replace the first occurrence
Hehlo
```

You can also convert your string into a list

```
>>> s = 'Hello'
>>> s = [x for x in s]
>>> s
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

In here you can replace anything by anything, like so:

```
>>> s[3] = 'h'
>>> s
['H', 'e', 'l', 'h', 'o']
```

When you're done with replacing whatever you want, you can use the `.join()` method to make your list a string again like so:

```
>>> s = ''.join(s) #separator goes in between the quotes
>>> s
Helho
```